# Auto-arrange in Visio doesn't arrange annotations

Tags: microsoft-visio

I have a Brainstorm diagram and some topics/subtopics may have annotations connected to them. Whenever I do an auto-arrange Visio seems to successfully arrange the topics and subtopics, but leaves the annotations where they are creating a mess.

This applies to simply moving a topic/subtopic too. Normally if you move a topic, Visio will move the subtopics along with it (but not annotations). Which is not always desirable and I wish there was a way to elect whether or not to move subtopics.

Is there a way to get Visio to move annotations when auto-arranging topics/subtopics? 
Perhaps I can use something other than an annotation?

Comment: How did you add the annotations in Visio drawing? Using Comments or Callout? If you are using Callout, you can associate it with the shape. Then you can move the shape and the callout can move with it.

Comment: They're Callouts for sure. How do I go about associating them? Put it in as an answer if you like

Comment: I tried grouping them but Visio complains saying "The shape you're trying to group with is a Brainstorm shape. Brainstorm shapes cannot be grouped"

Answer (score 0):

Whether the shapes are Review comments or callouts, the Brainstorming software does not know about them and cannot move them.

However, there is a way within the shapesheet. First you need to know the name of the shape you wish to associate the comment with. For this either use the Drawing Explorer or slect the shape and use ribbon Developer -> Shape Name.
Now select the callout and set its PinX and PinY cells to:

PinX = !PinX

PinY = !PinY
or to place the callout a small distance from the topic shape:
PinX = !PinX + 15mm

You could also protect this formula with:

PinX = GUARD(!PinX)

etc.